# Rails Keep User Login after changing domain url and redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I am using Rails as my backend and UI is handled with CSS and JS/Jquery.

We have multiple organization and companies. Company is tied with Organization and AdminUser are tied with company. Each organization have different urls. I am working on building a feature where we have role named ***"super_user"*** .

After successfull login we have created an popup modal which shows 2 dropdowns to select organization and company and after saving different organization and company it must change to that organization url and route to default page, alhtough it should not logout from the session.

Explanation with an example:-

ABC is Organization with domain url - abc.com

XYZ is Organization with domain url - xyz.com

Rohan is adminuser with role as super_admin and its tied with XYZ organization.
After successfull login user is redirected to ***teams/choose_group*** an popup appears and it selects ABC organization from dropdown and after clicking the Save button it redirect to update method of (url = teams/admin_user/891). After updating the record from XYZ organization to ABC organization, the domain url must be change and it must redirect to ***teams/choose_group*** page.

**Note:- Currently I am trying same but user is been logout first time only and needs login, so I am thinking the session is getting stored in web browser. Is there any way around to handle this. reset_session will destory the session and redirects to login page after changing domain url. Is there any workaround for same.**

Here is some code snippet I can provide,

```
def update
    @admin_user = AdminUser.find_by_id(params[:id]) if @admin_user.nil?
    if current_teams_admin_user.super_admin?
      params[:admin_user][:company_id] = Company.find_by_name(params[:company]).id if params[:company].present?
      params[:admin_user][:organization_id] = Organization.find_by_name(params[:admin_user][:organization]).id if params[:admin_user][:organization].present?
    end
    if @admin_user.update_attributes(admin_user_params)
      if current_teams_admin_user.super_admin?
        new_url = "https://#{@admin_user.admin_user_organization_url}#{teams_choose_groups_path}"
        flash[:success] = "#{update_flash_message(@admin_user)} is now at #{@admin_user.company_name}"
        redirect_to new_url and return
      end
      flash[:notice] = "#{update_flash_message(@admin_user)} successfully updated!"
      redirect_to edit_teams_admin_user_path(@admin_user)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Comment: Injecting things *into* `params` seems like a mistake here.

Comment: I am not aware of this please let me know what will be the improvement here. Also its not related to the question I have asked.

Comment: `session` is an abstraction around something that is stored in the browser, effectively building on a cookie.

Comment: I understand the concern of your point but how can we carry out same cookie to different domain url. Thats what I am looking for

Comment: What sort of different URL? A subdomain of the same base domain, or completely different domain? If you pin your session cookie to the base domain, it'll persist across all subdomains, like `x.example.com` benefits from cookies set at `*.example.com`.

Comment: different URL are some like `tadman_user.com` and `weict_00723.com`. there are no subdomains to handle this. I also checked out the inside cookies the session for user is always different after domain url change from my production logs. @tadman

Comment: You can't share sessions across different domains, as these are anchored to cookies that are pinned to a specific domain (plus subdomains). You can have a "single sign-on" (SSO) using OAuth2 and such, but directly porting over the `session` is not easily done here. Effectively each session is locked to a specific domain, and as far as the browser (user-agent) is concerned, a different domain is an entirely different web site.

Comment: I understand your point thanks for clearing out. So on conclusion its decided that we cannot handle this on different domains.